# Executing RSH command using exec() in PHP

Tags: php, rsh

I am having trouble using `rsh` in the PHP `exec()` command.  The error that I'm getting is: `Could not create directory '/nonexistent/.ssh'`.

It appears that this is because Apache runs as the user `nobody` who does not have a home directory, therefore it cannot find/create a .ssh directory.  What I would do from the terminal is something similar to:

```
sudo su - user_with_home_directory
/usr/bin/rsh -n -l username myserver.com /path/to/my/script.sh
```

But I am not aware of how to do this using PHP's `exec()` command.  I don't want to (and cannot) give the nobody user a home directory just to get the problem to go away.

Any help is greatly appreciated to helping me figure out how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems as if the `rsh` on the server that I'm using is Kerberos enabled, which in turn uses SSH to do the authentication.  This is what was causing the search for a `.ssh` directory.

To solve this, I created an SSH key and stored it on the filesystem at a different location other than the `.ssh` directory, again to prevent from creating a home directory for the `nobody` user.  Then using SSH, I specified the `-i` option that points to my generated SSH key, allowing me to execute the script remotely without the need to login with a password.